# Get name of property as string instead of property value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, typescript

In a binding handler, if I have a binding like below:

```
<div data-bind="someHandler { value : valueOnModel }"></div>
```

And the following code for my binding handler:

```
class someHandler : KnockoutBindingHandler {
  init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    var va = valueAccessor();
    var value = va.value;
    //How to get "valueOnModel" here??
    var valuePropertyName : string;

    var isVisible = data[valuePropertyName + "_isVisible"];
  }
}
```

The above is what I want to achieve, however I do not know how set valuePropertyName with the above?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: So you want to get the property name instead of the value?

Comment: @Stefan Yeah, similar to the concept of reflection - I am trying to set up some generic functionality on my binding handlers

Comment: @LukeHennerley Have you tried any of the answers or used your own solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well, my answer may seem not so elegant, just an idea - ko wraps your variable with `function() { ... }` inside value accessor, so why just not do the reverse:

```
valueAccessor.toString().match(/{return (\w+) }/)[1]
```

I'm not an expert in regEx, but this works on my simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c439S/)

Comment: I like this approach! My answer, which I took from that other question, works OK in a view-model, outside of a custom binding. But if you are in a custom binding, Ilya's approach feels nicer.

Comment: @sifriday, thanks mate! I assumed that TO needs this in custom binder since he uses one in his original question.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really similar question also active at the moment:

[Knockout how to get data-bind keys and value observables using element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116043/knockout-how-to-get-data-bind-keys-and-value-observables-using-element/25118251#25118251)

I had a think, and gave an answer, but I couldn't find a perfect way to do it. I think KO has parsed 'valueOnModel' into various function references and it doesn't actually give you access to the strings it originally parsed out of the binding.

So I thought, maybe you can achieve what you need by reparsing the binding from the element?

```
    var binding_info = {};
    $($(element).attr("data-bind").split(",")).each(
        function(idx, binding) {
            var parts = binding.split(":")
            binding_info[parts[0].trim()] = parts[1].trim()
        }
    )
```

then once you have done that,

```
    binding_info.value
```

should return "valueOnModel"

There's a nice idea in the other Q about using:

http://joel.net/unobtrusive-data-binding-for-knockout-js

to define your bindings beforehand as a JS object. Then you would be able to use this object as a lookup in your binding handler.